# How to get customer group id by giving customer group name in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1, customer-group

I need some functionality based on the response given by ERP.

I need to get the customer group id by using the customer group code?

How do I get customer group id by group name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the group name using the collection Filter. The below is a code that can be used with the block logic, but it can be used any other parts of the application.

Basically, we need to query this database table `customer_group`

```
protected $groupFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
}

/**
 * @param $id
 * @return string
 */
public function getGroupIdByName($name)
{
    $group = $this->groupFactory->create();

    $groupCollection = $group->getCollection();
    $groupCollection->addAttributetoFilter('customer_group_code',$name);

    return $groupCollection->getFirst();
}
```